# How can I set a Jest timeout based on an array length

Tags: jestjs

I want to set the timeout of a Jest test based on input for my test. Here is an example:

```
let someArray;

beforeAll(async () => {
   someArray = getFromInputFile()
});

test('my test', async () => {
   for (let someVariable of someArray) {
      doSomeAction(someVariable)
   }

}, 4000 * someArray.length);
```

I know it should take about 4000ms to execute `doSomeAction` one time, so how can I set the timeout of my Jest test to adapt to a changing input value, whether it be 1 time or 20 times. When I tried the above code, it failed saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`